# How to do prototypal inheritance in this case?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

How can I do inheritance with this example.

**I'm trying to create an object literal that functions as a singleton. Within this I'd like to extract my classes. Next to that, these classes should inherit from each other when applicable**.

Like so:

```
var Singleton = {

    car: function() {
        this.engine= true;
    },

    ford: function() {
        this.color = 'red';
    }
};
```

**I'd like to let ford inherit from bar, but I can't do this**:

```
    ford: function() {
        this.color = 'red';
        this.prototype = new this.car();
    }
```

**Any ideas?**

Comment: To get started, use a constructor instead of object literals.

Comment: [JavaScript Inheritance Patterns](http://bolinfest.com/javascript/inheritance.php).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "bar inherit from foo"? Are foo and bar going to be used as constructor with `new` calls?

Comment: Yes they are. Also @Rob, why?

Comment: @Kriem Constructors are **functions**. Instances are created by prefixing a [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) operator, which creates an object which inherits methods from the constructor's prototype.

Comment: Right, but I want this to act like a type of 'singleton' object, containing methods that I can use. Those methods are objects, inheriting from each other. Do you get what I'm aiming for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Something = {

    foo: function() {
        this.greet = 'hello';
    },
    bar: function() {
        this.color = 'blue';
    }
};

Something.bar.prototype = new Something.foo();
alert((new Something.bar()).greet)
```

Here is a primer on [inheritance](http://elsamman.com/?p=4)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make `bar` inherit properties of `foo` then you could do something like this (note, that this way you will not have prototype properties inhereted though):

```
var Something = {
    foo: function() {
        this.greet = 'hello';
    },
    bar: function() {
        Something.foo.call(this);
        this.color = 'blue';
    }
};
```

And then use it like this:

```
var bar = new Something.bar();
bar.color // blue
bar.greet // hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
function Foo() {
    this.greet = "hi!";
}

Bar.prototype = new Foo;

function Bar(color) {
    Foo.apply(this.arguments);
    this.color = color;
}

var myBar = new Bar("red");
```

A `Bar` created this way will have both  `greet` and `color` properties. This method preserves Prototype properties.

Comment: Change `Foo.apply(this.arguments);` to `Foo.apply(this, arguments);`. Also, a little better way to create the prototype object would be `Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);`. Not terribly important for this simple example though.